# Bootstrap grid layout one box along others

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I would like to arrange layout with bootstrap (using bootstrap 4) in way that one column goes along other columns on wide screen and on mobile it will be under each other, but the column which goes along the others is second in order.
I know how to do this in way that the highest column will be at the end of grid (I don't want it that way).
Here are examples how should look result

**Layout on Desktop should be like below image**
[image: Layout on Desktop]

**Layout on Mobile**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 has responsive floats for this scenario. You can you `pull-*-right` on the 2nd column for larger (desktop) widths..

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 pull-md-right">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-9">3</div>
    <div class="col-md-9">4</div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://codeply.com/go/N7rGhE72Kr